# Prediction of index in Lexicographical ordering of binary sequences?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose all $n$ sequences of 0's and 1's were displayed in Lexicographical order. Can the index of sequences that sum to $k$ be predicted?

Comment: Are you sure you mean permutations? a permutation is a fixed set of elements in different orders.

Comment: My underlying problem relates to sequences of n coin flips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Better stated question}$: given all possible sequences of $n$ coin flips (a total of $2^n$ many), arrange them lexicographically. Can we find the index of those sequences that have $k$ heads?

$\textbf{Solution}:$ First let us consider a small case example where $n = 10$ and $k = 4$:
\begin{cases}
0000001111 & = 2^{3} + 2^{2} + 2^1 + 2^0 \quad (\text{all $k$ 1's are at the end})\\
0000010111 & = 2^{4} + 2^{2} + 2^1 + 2^0 \quad (k-1\text{ 1's are at the end; one 1 popped to the left})\\
0000011011 & = 2^{4} + 2^{3} + 2^1 + 2^0 \quad (k-2\text{ 1's are at the end; one 1 popped to the left})\\
0000011101 & = 2^{4} + 2^{3} + 2^2 + 2^0\\
0000011110 & = 2^{4} + 2^{3} + 2^2 + 2^1\\
0000100111 & = 2^{5} + 2^{2} + 2^1 + 2^1\\
0000101011 & = 2^{5} + 2^{3} + 2^1 + 2^0\\
& \vdots\\
1111100000 &= 2^{10} + 2^{9} + 2^8 + 2^7 \quad (\text{all} \ k \ \text{1's are to the left})
\end{cases}

Note for the equality I'm just translating binaries into decimals. For the general case, if $k > n$ then no such sequence exist, so assume $k \leq n$. Then the sequence we desire is
\begin{cases}
0....01...1 & = 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + 2^{k-3} +... 2^0 \quad (\text{all $k$ 1's are at the end})\\
0...01011...1 & = 2^{k} + 2^{k-2} + 2^{k-3} + ... + 2^0 \quad (k-1\text{ 1's are at the end; one 1 popped to the left})\\
& \vdots\\
1...10....0 &= 2^n + 2^{n-1} + ... + 2^{n-k+1}
\end{cases}

so the answer is yes.

Comment: The number of 1's in a binary string is called the Hamming weight.

Comment: Ben10, could you please provide a concrete example using your solution? Perhaps n = 3, k = 2?

Comment: If $n = 5$ and $k = 3$, then the sequence is given by $\{00111, 01011, 01101, 01110, 10011, 10101, 10110, 11001, 11010, 11100\}$. You know these must be all because there are exactly ${5 \choose 3} = 10$ many of them. You can translate them into base 10 numbers if you want.

Comment: Ben, I am still uncertain. I see your example gives the correct sub-sequences. But I am unsure how your notation above relates to the index of each sequence in the lexicographic arrangement. The power in your first line goes from k, k+1 ... 0. In the next line it goes from k+1, k-1 ... 0. I am not seeing a clear pattern.

Comment: sorry! there was a typo. The first one is k,k-1,...,0, and the next is k+1,k-1,...,0. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Ben, not exactly. I still can't understand the powers. Should the second column, second row power not be k? I am prepared to accept your answer, but I still need a worked example.

Comment: Okay, so I added an example that I tried to match up with the general case solution (which when doing so I realized the general case solution goes up to $k-1$ instead of $k$....another typo.... sorry friend)

Comment: Hopefully it makes sense now....? I agree the indexing is quite confusing